# Reason for query failure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to find out why my query is failing whenever this php script is run. The error is: Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: - Error: in /home/eland/u5/kbecs/w1268094/public_html/UWSU-Debating-Portal/admin/inventory.php on line 19

and this is the bit of code around line 19:

```
$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['question']);
$venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['venue']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['questiondate']);
//See if question is identical to another question in the table
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT qQuestionNo FROM DebateQuestion WHERE question='$question'LIMIT 1");
$questionMatch = mysqli_num_rows($link, $sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(db_conx), E_USER_ERROR);; //count the output amount
if ($questionMatch>0){
echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Question" into the table, <a href="inventory.php">Click here</a>';
exit();
}
//Add the question to the database 
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO DebateQuestion (qQuestion, qDebateVenue, qDate)
VALUES($link,'$question','$venue','$date'") or die (mysqli_error());
$qid = mysqli_insert_id();
header("Location: inventory.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: which one is line 19?

Comment: So sorry here it is: $questionMatch = mysqli_num_rows($link, $sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(db_conx), E_USER_ERROR);; //count the output amount

Comment: You have two `;;`'s on that line.

Comment: @BeatAlex It's empty statement and it's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting space before `LIMIT` in

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT qQuestionNo FROM DebateQuestion WHERE question='$question'LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm more interested in what downvoter can say.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_num_rows` only takes a result object. Try:

```
$questionMatch = mysqli_num_rows($sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(db_conx), E_USER_ERROR); //count the output amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing because of awfully inconsistent and untidy code. And you have no idea of it due to **lack of error reporting.**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

at the top of your code will help to reveal most silly mistakes you made.

like with `db_conx` which is a strange constant defined nowhere
and with `$sql` variable which contains anything but SQL code.

```
$sql = "SELECT qQuestionNo FROM DebateQuestion WHERE question='$question' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link)." [$sql]");
if (mysqli_num_rows($link)){
    echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate blah blah';
    exit();
}
```

it have to be at the very least

Answer (score -1):

try adding space before `LIMIT` keyword:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT qQuestionNo FROM DebateQuestion WHERE question='".$question."' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Please, please, please learn SQL rules before reaching for "Answer" button. Or at least test your answer in console first. is it too hard?